# Schema is not validating "Itemprop"

Tags: html, schema

This the code:

```
<a href="https://www.mim-essay.com" class="logo-imgContainer navbar-brand ml-3 d-flex align-items-center">
<img id="_logo6" itemprop="logo" fetchpriority="high" src="https://www.mim-essay.com/images/MiM-Essay-Sticky-Logo-6.png" alt="mim essay" class="logo-img"></a>
```

Why I am getting this error?

```
Error:- https://www.mim-essay.com/images/MiM-Essay-Sticky-Logo-6.png (The property logo is not recognised by the schema (e.g. schema.org) for an object of type WebPage.)
```

What should I do ?

I have tried and change `<itemprop>` from logo to different value but still getting the same error.

Comment: What is `itemprop="logo"` for and why do you need it?  Where are you being told that this is an error?